# What does xmlrpc.php do and how can I use it?

Tags: 7

I have seen `xmlrpc.php` but I haven't found much documentation out there. Is it possible to use this directly without any additional modules? Where is the canonical documentation for it?

Is `xmlrpc.php` what is refered to [here](https://groups.drupal.org/node/50008) as "drupal's xmlrpc"? If that statement is correct `xmlrpc.php` would be only for the blog module in core.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I don't think we can give you full XML RPC manual here. See https://www.drupal.org/search/site/xml%20rpc

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find a clear answer to my question on d.o. I rephrased the body of the question to make it a bit more narrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use it for other RPCs. [Example xml-rpc post for user.update](https://www.drupal.org/node/1854226) shows an example of a *user.update* method call.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>user.update</methodName>
   <params>
     <param>
       <struct>
         <member>
           <name>uid</name>
           <value><int>38</int></value>
         </member>
       </struct>
       <struct>
         <member>
           <name>name</name>
           <value><string>diana.ruiz12</string></value>
         </member>
         <member>
           <name>mail</name>
            <value><string>ndy.r@eeuwkern.org</string></value>
         </member>
         <member>
           <name>pass</name>
           <value><string>candy9223</string></value>
         </member>
       </struct>
     </param>
   </params>
</methodCall>
```

It doesn't look like a widely used feature, and it will be moved out of core in Drupal 8.

See also [Services Tutorials and Examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/113697).