# How to automate setting up Services or RESTws?

Tags: 7, services

It looks like [xmlrpc.php is of almost no use](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125995/what-does-xmlrpc-php-do-and-how-can-i-use-it). I want to use XML-RPC to control my sites but I don't want to set up Services or [RESTws](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) manually on dozens of sites. It doesn't look like Services has support for Features.

Is there a way to automate setting up Services or RESTws on many sites at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Services module doesn't have any Drush integration (Drush being the standard way of running code against multiple sites at once). So I would assume that nothing currently exists that does what you're looking for.

However, Services does use the ctools plugin API, so you can probably piggy-back off that to some degree. It will mean you need to code a Drush plugin yourself to manage the export/import, but you can probably get most of the boilerplate code from somewhere like the [Drush CTools Export Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus) module.

Bottom line, I think it's unlikely you'll find a pre-existing solution for this, you'll probably have to get stuck in and make your own.

Comment: Darn. Fortunately [it looks like](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) this will be better in d8.

Comment: Yeah REST is in core in D8, and I'd wager resources/servers will be config entities, so you'll be able to import/export them easily.